# Визуальный редактор для сеошника (контент-менеджера) - как настроить адаптивность изображений?

Tags: modx, wysiwyg

Есть ModX revo. Есть контент-менеджер(сеошник), который использует визуальный редактор и ему надо, чтобы без помощи программиста он мог вставлять изображения в любой части текста и они должны быть адаптивными.
max-width:100% и height:auto не помогает. Как реализовать ума не приложу, ведь помимо того что изображения в виз.редакторе задаются пикселями, так они еще  и могут быть вставлены сбоку от текста так, что потом при уменьшении разрешения этот текст сдвигают вниз(вверх), а не адаптируются вместе с текстом.

Answer (score 0):

я думаю, тут дело не столько в modx, сколько в css.

Указанный вопрос решается там, потому как сео-шник хочет просто работать в визуальном редакторе. Значит никакие настройки его могут не удовлетворить.

Думаю, можно попробовать скриптом ловить все картинки из контента (или где там он работает в визуальном редакторе) и присваивать им определенный класс и стилизовать в css или стилизовать там же в скрипте.

Ну а при уменьшении размера, сдвигать картинку вверх или низ и располагать посредине страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Спс за ответ. Дело все-таки оказалось не в css. Просто в CKeditor(виз.редактор) надо было заставить контент-менеджера убрать все значения в пикселях (ширину картинки ставить в %, а значение высоты вообще удалить). Применительно к MODx это можно сделать в CKeditor на плагине IMAGE(на IMAGE2 уже не получится, там значения можно ставить только в пикселях).